# Bootstrap left center/right center aligned navbar items not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/7zrrknn0/

```
CSS CODE FOR CONTAINER:
.navbar-brand
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
.container-fluid    {
width: 1220px;
}
```

If you take a look at the jsfiddle I have and look at the result window, it seems fine, but when the window is minimized, the navbar items don't change size in accordance to the window size. 
I'm trying to keep the container/boxed layout I have going on, while also keeping the responsiveness of bootstrap. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all take a look at your code. Your whole content code is not even in the `<body>`. Secondly I can't even the see your navbar items. Third since you are using twitter bootstrap you don't even need to `position: absolute` your elements cause that make big trouble for adjusting it for every single device. Fourth don't use the `type='text/css'` for the `<link>` cause you have already declared the document as HTML5 document. Try to make your code semantic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simply that you're overriding the width of the .container-fluid class forcing it to be 1220px regardless of how wide the viewport is.

Either change your container class to be `max-width: 1220px;` as in the demo below or use the built in `container` class.  The container class has the following fixed widths at each of the Bootstrap break points by default:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 970px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1170px;
    }
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/7zrrknn0/1/)